# How to optimize opening and closing excel workbooks to extract data to run faster

Tags: performance, vba, excel, excel-2007

I currently know of two methods to open and close excel workbooks to extract data from them to summarize in a single workbook.

The first method is as follows:

```
Dim wbDataSheet As Workbook
For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
    Set wbDataSheet = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum), 0, True)

     'Capture data

    wbDataSheet.Close (False)
Next FNum
```

The second is this:

```
Dim XL As New Excel.Application
For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
    With XL
        .Workbooks.Open FileName:=MyPath & MyFiles(FNum), ReadOnly:=True
        .Visible = False
    End With

    'Capture Data

    XL.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next FNum
```

My dilemma is this:

Method 1 is faster (about .35 seconds/file for 1052 files) but it explodes my task bar as it opens new workbooks (making it near impossible to select a different excel workbook) and for some reason my code can be easily broken by pressing shift more than once or holding it at all, forcing me to start the code over.

Method 2 is noticeably slower (about .56 seconds/file for 1052 files) but since the excel application is hidden my taskbar remains usable and pressing shift doesn't break the code.

What I want to know is, is there a way to run method 1 without ruining my taskbar or having shift stop the code? Alternatively, is there a way to speed up method two to speeds near method 1?

*Note: I am already using the code below to optimize my speed and limiting vba/workbook interaction. Besides the methods to access the workbooks, the rest of the code in each scenario is identical.

```
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

Comment: First question - How are you grabbing the data from the workbooks? Could it be done via formulas / ADO rather than opening / closing? Also, if they're `xlsx` workbooks, maybe the better way would be to use some kind of XML tricks.... There might be better solutions for grabbing data from such a large amount of workbooks oftentimes... Truly for such a large set of books, I'd probably go with ADO, though if at all possible...

Comment: Agree with @JohnBustos -- look in to other ways of obtaining data from the files such as ADO or for small amounts of data even the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ADO, do you have some sample code or a good source for information about it? From what I have seen, it looks like SQL is used to get the data - unfortunately, my data is spread out on a form other people have filled out and I don't know if that will work unless there is a way to get data from specific cells?

Comment: After some digging I was able to find an example that illustrates how to do what I want with ADO [Here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm). It is able to go through all of the 1052 files in just over 3 minutes (~.175 seconds/file)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example code for calling the `GetValue` function which uses `ExecuteExcel4Macro`:

```
Sub test()
Dim p As String, f As String, s as String, a as String
 
   p = "C:\Users\User\Documents\"
   f = "Example.xlsx"
   s = "Sheet1"  'This is the name of the Sheet in your file
   a = "D56"     'Range of the value you want I'm not sure if you can pull more than cell's value or not

   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F21") = GetValue(p, f, s, a)  'Transfer the value
End Sub
```

`GetValue` function:

```
Function GetValue(Path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Dir(Path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & Path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I was able to consistently extract all data at about .07 seconds per file, halving the average time to run! I had tried to figure out the ExecuteExcel4Macro function but the online references seemed to be lacking. Do you have any good references that demonstrate how to use ExecuteExcel4Macro so I can use it for other situations?

Comment: Not off the top of my head...this application is the only one I've used.