# Processing large amounts of data in macro-enabled workbooks [Excel/Other]

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have 15 or so workbooks with a large amount of data (2000 rows, ~120000 Active Cells in the sheet I want to use) and I'm trying to create basically a search engine where someone can type a criteria and then excel or something else returns any rows where that condition is met.

I have something like this working

Pseudo code

```
Map drive (files are stored on sharepoint)
Loop workbookdata1 to workbookdata15
    Copy data from sheet to new sheet in workbookMAIN
    Loop through columns, keeping only relevant columns, deleting the rest
    Loop through rows, deleting row if first cell = blank or "xxx" 
Next workbookdata
Compile all of the data from the newly generated sheet
Make it look nice and readable
```

This works, but it takes 45mins - hour to run because every sheet it opens updates links (all 2000 rows) and then having to filter out all of the unwanted data.

What are my options for speeding this up? Can I process the data quicker using Access or MATLAB, or coding something that would?

Comment: i don't know if Access or MATBLAB are faster, i think Access should be. Anyway this should definitly be possible with Excel too. But there are a lot of things to look at. First opening the workbook the Default way is slow. ADO or ExecuteExcel4Macro (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287549/how-to-optimize-opening-and-closing-excel-workbooks-to-extract-data-to-run-faste) would be faster. Copying data can also be done very slow or quite fast. But you will have to post your correct code to get more help.

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: If you are frequently referencing the worksheet as you process your data, this will be very slow.  You can expect significant (ten-fold?) speed increase by using VBA arrays, Collections and possibly user defined objects to gather your data before writing it onto the worksheet.  With the amount of your data, you may have to do this in stages, but that should still afford you a significant speed increase.

Comment: I;ve never heard of using ADO or ExcuteExcel4Macro before, I'll look into that. I will post the code when I get a chance, I'll have to change some of the names in it.

Comment: When I was referring to code, it's just VBA, Code Review looks handy, but is that for actual programming as opposed to scripts like VBA?

Comment: I'll look into using arrays, it looks like that could be handy - I thought that something like that would be RAM-intensive and so copying, pasting and clearing the memory would have been quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts.

1) If the main culprit is the updating of links, then stop the updating on opening with with

```
Workbooks.Open fullFileName, UpdateLinks:=False
```

2) I suspect it's time consuming to copy everything and then delete what you don't need - is this really necessary?
Could you try cycling through the data and identify what is relevant and copy that? 
I guess it might depend on how you are doing your searching but if you are going through and testing every row anyway (not sure if you need to do this) then you could identify the first row that meets the criteria and carry on until you hit row which doesn't meet the criteria. Then copy and paste the rows (or sections thereof) starting from the first and ending with the last that met your criteria. Once you've done this, carry on cycling through your data.
You might even be able to collect all the ranges in a sheet (e.g. with a Union statement) and finally copy them all in one statement once you reach the end of the sheet.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. It might help to know more about your data and the types of criteria you have.

Edit 1: Yes that will override the updating of links. Also have you tried setting calculation mode to manual and making sure screen updating is set to false? These could be slowing you down signficantly.

Comment: I most of the time, the slow thing is accessing the Excel sheet and not copying the values (Depending on how it is copied...). I would recomment to copy the full value to an Array, and Loop throught that. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel

Comment: 1) ~Will that override any OnWorkbookOpen Macros with update links enabled?                                                                                                                       2) I suppose that gives fewer steps to run through, I did have it like that, and it was really slow as well mainly because the workbook it opens constantly updates whenever any change is made, even in read-only mode. I will give it a shot and get back to this thread with what helped improve.  The criteria are all strings, so I have a list of column headers that I want in a list, and just match and delet